# jsoup:how to get first element?

Tags: jsoup

Good day!
I try to parse site.
So, i can parse it with jsoup and parse string:

```
[class=newsList] ul[class] li[class=dark],li[class=light]
```

But, site has two divs with class=newsList. :

```
  <div class="innerBlock" id="lastNews">
    ...
    ....
  <div class="innerBlock" id="lastNews">
```

How to get first one?

Thank you!

Comment: the HTML you posted contains two times the same id. That is very poor HTML. Maybe a mistake? Please describe in more detail what you try to achieve and what you so far have tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you have the fragment of HTML which contains the `divs` in an `Elements` instance called doc.

Then here you are three ways of doing it :

- CSS way:

  ```
  doc.select("div:first-child");
  ```
- more generic CSS way:

  ```
  doc.select("div:nth-child(1)");
  ```
- programmatic way:

  ```
  doc.select("div").first();
  ```

The first two giving an `Elements` instance with only an element in it and the third one giving an `Element` instance.